# Multi Threading in Synchronous infinite while loop: Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I am facing an issue while running multithread. I need a solution similar to [Goroutine](https://go.dev/tour/concurrency/1) in GoLang.

Here is the code that I need to run in multithread.

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def get_response():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get('https://swapi.dev/api/starships/9/') as response:
            print(await response.json())

def make_sync_req(subscriber):
    while True:
        asyncio.sleep(2)
        print('running after sleep: ', subscriber)
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(get_response())


subscriber = ["subscriber1", "subscriber2", "subscribe3"]
for s in subscriber:
  print(s)
  make_sync_req(s)


print('wait here')
asyncio.sleep(500)
```

In the above code, I need to run multiple `make_sync_req` functions in parallel.
This issue is related to NATS where I need to subscribe to multiple subjects.

Please provide me with an approach to solve the following problem.

I tried the following code

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import threading

async def get_response():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get('https://swapi.dev/api/starships/9/') as response:
            print(await response.json())

def make_sync_req(subscriber):
    while True:
        asyncio.sleep(2)
        print('running after sleep: ', subscriber)
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(get_response())


subscriber = ["subscriber1", "subscriber2", "subscribe3"]
for s in subscriber:
  print(s)
  thread = threading.Thread(target=make_sync_req, args=(s,))
  thread.daemon = True                            # Daemonize thread
  thread.start()


print('wait here')
asyncio.sleep(500)
```

This gives the following error

```
python main.py 
subscriber1
subscriber2
running after sleep:  subscriber2
C:\Users\Venugopal_Hegde\go\src\test-python-async\main.py:14: DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop       
  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
subscribe3
Exception in thread Thread-2 (make_sync_req):
Traceback (most recent call last):
running after sleep:  subscribe3
  File "C:\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
wait here
C:\Users\Venugopal_Hegde\go\src\test-python-async\main.py:12: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'sleep' was never awaited      
  asyncio.sleep(2)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
running after sleep:  subscriber1
Exception in thread Thread-3 (make_sync_req):
    self.run()
Exception in thread Thread-1 (make_sync_req):
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 946, in run
  File "C:\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
C:\Users\Venugopal_Hegde\go\src\test-python-async\main.py:27: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'sleep' was never awaited      
  asyncio.sleep(500)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
    self.run()
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Venugopal_Hegde\go\src\test-python-async\main.py", line 14, in make_sync_req
  File "C:\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 946, in run
Fatal Python error: _enter_buffered_busy: could not acquire lock for <_io.BufferedWriter name='<stderr>'> at interpreter shutdown, possibly due to daemon threads
Python runtime state: finalizing (tstate=0x00000276561ced40)

Current thread 0x00005568 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>

Extension modules: multidict._multidict, yarl._quoting_c, aiohttp._helpers, aiohttp._http_writer, aiohttp._http_parser, aiohttp._websocket, frozenlist._frozenlist (total: 7)
```

Comment: I think you cant use `asyncio.sleep` under synchronous function

Comment: `goroutine` is Go's implementation of coroutines. Coroutines aren't threads even though the underlying runtime *may* use threads to execute them. You can't just call a coroutine from an asynchronous method in either language - you need to use `go` in Go too. The [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) docs show how to use `asyncio.run` to start async execution at the top level and start an async event loop, how to use `create_task` to run coroutines concurrently and how to use `await` to asynchronously await them

Comment: *Don't* use threads with asyncio. Start subscriber tasks with `create_task`. For async operations to work, `async` needs to flow all the way to the top level and a call to `asyncio.run`. Even if you start 5 tasks with `create_task` you'll need to make `main` a coroutine to await all tasks without blocking. Instead of channels you can use [asyncio queues](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run async function as a thread, you can use `python-worker` ([link](https://pypi.org/project/python-worker/))

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import threading

async def get_response():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get('https://swapi.dev/api/starships/9/') as response:
            print(await response.json())

@async_worker
async def make_sync_req(subscriber):
    while True:
        asyncio.sleep(2)
        print('running after sleep: ', subscriber)
        await get_response()


subscriber = ["subscriber1", "subscriber2", "subscribe3"]
for s in subscriber:
    print(s)
    asyncio.run(make_sync_req(s))


print('wait here')
asyncio.sleep(500)
```